# What can I do to fix this Tumblr Custom HTML code for header links?

Tags: html, hyperlink, tumblr

I'm trying to edit Tumblr Custom HTML to add another header link to my Tumblr theme.

I have searched stackoverflow for "Tumblr" "Custom HTML" "block:Pages" and "link" but have not found the bug in my code that's leading to the following problem:

1. I copy and pasted

   ```
   <li><a href="/archive/">{lang:Archive}</a></li>
   ```
2. I then changed

   ```
   "/archive/"
   ```

   to

   ```
   "/submit/"
   ```

   and

   ```
   {lang:Archive}
   ```

   to

   ```
   {lang:Submit a Post}
   ```

I end up with a webpage with a header link that, when clicked on, takes you to the correct page, but there is no text for that link. Please see a [screenshot](http://monosnap.com/image/81gmztZ7tZRFWSdu9sWhWdSyB.png) of the problem and the [website](http://adesignadaychallenge.tumblr.com) I'm trying to fix.

I've included a code snippet so that you can help me troubleshoot. Thank you!

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="headerwrap">
    <div class="span-18" id="header">
        <div class="span-18 last"><ul>
            <li><a href="/" class="name active">{Title}</a></li>
            {block:HasPages}
                {block:Pages}<li><a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li>{/block:Pages}
            {block:HasPages}
            <li><a href="/random/">{lang:Random post}</a></li>
            <li><a href="/submit/">{lang:Submit a Post}</a></li>
            <li><a href="/archive/">{lang:Archive}</a></li>
        </ul></div>
    </div></div>
    {block:IfHeaderImage}<img src="{image:Header}"/>{/block:IfHeaderImage}
    <div class="span-24"><div class="span-5 blue_striped">&nbsp;</div><div class="span-18 last"><p>{Description}</p></div></div>
    <hr/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `{lang:}` tag lets you specify an English string that should be displayed in the user's language, but it only works with a predefined set of strings that can be found here:

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/localizing_themes

You can "request a string be added", but I have no idea how long that would take. Best would probably be to drop the `{lang:}` wrapper and just include the text directly:

```
<li><a href="/submit/">Submit a Post</a></li>
```

The string won't be localized for non-English users, but oh well!